# Elasticsearch - Convert Json Strin to XcontentBuilder

Tags: elasticsearch

I was using elasticsearch 6.2.2. and this is how I convert json string to Xcontentbuilder.

```
XContentBuilder builder = JsonXContent.contentBuilder().prettyPrint();
XContentParser parser = JsonXContent.jsonXContent.createParser(NamedXContentRegistry.EMPTY, jsonObj.toString());
builder.copyCurrentStructure(parser);
```

I worked well until I updated elasticsearch 6.3+.
There is error on ES 6.3+ with same code.

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type The method
>   createParser(NamedXContentRegistry, DeprecationHandler, String) in the
>   type JsonXContent is not applicable for the arguments
>   (NamedXContentRegistry, String)   test.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Compile Error** has called out: your `createParser` miss a  `DeprecationHandler` **parameter**.

So you should set the `DeprecationHandler`, for example:

```
JsonXContent.jsonXContent.createParser(NamedXContentRegistry.EMPTY,
                                      LoggingDeprecationHandler.INSTANCE, 
                                      jsonObj.toString());
```